# Cannot build cordova android app

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap-cli

Today I wanted to update my app in google play store but got the following error:
[image]

My config.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<widget 
    id="com.bla.blabla.bla"
    version="1.3.8"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
    xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">

    <name>MyApp</name>

    <author>MyName</author>

    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />

    <content src="index.html"/>

    <access origin="*"/> 
    <allow-navigation href="*" />

    <!-- START: Android and iOS Quirks -->
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>

    <!-- START: Android section -->
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="17" />

    <!-- android quirks -->
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />

    <platform name="android">
        <splash src="www/resources/device/android/splash/land/hdpi.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/resources/device/android/splash/land/hdpi.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="www/resources/device/android/splash/land/hdpi.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/resources/device/android/splash/land/hdpi.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

        <splash src="www/resources/device/android/splash/port/hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/resources/device/android/splash/port/ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="www/resources/device/android/splash/port/mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/resources/device/android/splash/port/xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>

        <icon src="www/resources/device/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="www/resources/device/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="www/resources/device/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="www/resources/device/android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
    </platform>
     <!-- END: Android section -->

</widget>
```

My build script looks like:

```
    call cordova platform add android

    call cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
    call cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
    call cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
    call cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
    call cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
    call cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
    call cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
    call cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-opener2

    call cordova build android
```

What could be the problem? Some months ago this script worked. I searched a lot in the web but did not find the solution. Mostly I read that the solution is to edit the AndroidManifest.xml but I am in cordova and not in a native android app development so I cannot edit the AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now I resolved it by installing specific version of cordova:

```
npm install -g cordova@5.4.0
```

Before there was cordova 6.0.0 installed. I have no idea what changed from 5.4.0 to 6.0.0.